# What is producing the Wheel Frames?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am trying to work out how to wire up my custom robots wheels?

I fired up my turtlebot and via rosrun tf view_frames ( I have to be running roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch)

```
Frame wheel_left_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame wheel_right_link exists with parent base_link.
```

However my custom robot has no such frames and I am trying to work out what creates these frames.
My Custom frame is running Hector_slam and a Navigation stack

```
Exception thrown:"odom" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist. 
The current list of frames is:
Frame base_frame exists with parent map.
Frame scanmatcher_frame exists with parent map.
Frame laser exists with parent base_frame.
```

I am just trying to work out whats going on

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254365/what-is-producing-the-wheel-frames?/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have asked this question a few away, the bit i needed to add was.  I think I also need the differential package to

This seems to advertises the parts of the robot URDF(joints etc) to RVIZ.  The errors went away

---

Originally posted by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) with karma: 202 on 2017-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0